# Imagick stopped working after upgrading to OS X Yosemite

Tags: imagemagick, osx-mavericks, imagick, osx-yosemite

Imagick used to work normally on Mavericks before making the upgrade to Yosemite.

Any suggestion why it stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

Yosemite ships with a [php](/questions/tagged/php) version of 5.5.14. You'll need to reinstall all your previous PECL modules, and reconfigure your `/etc/php.ini` for the new extensions path `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212`.

Comment: Can you please be more specific...I have MAMP PRO...do I need to reinstall its PECL modules? And what about the new entension path/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212? Thanks!

Comment: If your using MAMP PRO, ensure you've updated to the latest version. If issues still exist, author a bug report [directly with vender](http://bugs.mamp.info).

Comment: I have filed a bug report to the author of MAMP PRO...and they're currently working on this issue. I'll post the answer whenever I get a reply.